# How to get apps of host OS to Virtualbox guest OS?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-8-preview

Is there any way to get apps of my Windows 7 to the newly installed Windows 8 RP which is running on virtualbox? I would like to get my apps on Windows 8.

Comment: You will need to install them again in the VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by apps you mean applications/normal windows software packages, you'll probably have to get their original installer and install them in Windows 8 again.

You can use the shared folder feature to make a folder (e.g. where you keep all the installers) in your host available to the guest.

Comment: no other way>>>?

Answer (score 0):

Install apps on the Windows 8 VM just like you would on a regular PC. After all, that’s the point of virtualisation.